# Alignment wrong on a SPFX web part

Tags: spfx, office-ui-fabric-react

I am newbie on SPFX with react but I have created this :

[image]

but I need to align the left hand label with all the command buttons and get the background colour the same, the id label is a little bit lower than command buttons. Any ideas ?

Here is my code for the first bit

```
    <span className="ms-fontColour-neutralDark ">ID : 80</span>


    <CommandBarButton

        data-automation-id="test2"
        iconProps={{ iconName: 'Mail' }}
        text="Forward Case"

      />
```

I am trying to get my SPAN lined up with the commandbar button. Hopefully someone can help me.